# YouTube video not showing in HTML5 WebView in Android 4.0 and upper Android versions

Tags: android, youtube, html5-video

I have to play YouTube video inside my application. I have used HTML5 WebView to play this video.

Video is playing fine for the OS version bellow 4.0.

Above 4.0 (4.1.2, 4.2), the video is not showing. Audio is playing, but the screen becomes black, no video displayed. In this situation, if I touch on the lower right corner of the screen, then the video displays, but video gets flickered and it is not stopped by pressing the back button.

I have to play the video for all versions. I have tested it in Galaxy S3 version 4.1.2 and Nexus version 4.2.

Comment: Why don't you play the video in VideoView or MediaPlayer? (you don't have to download it, they support streamming)

Comment: Android videoview does not play youtube video. Please provide me any better idea.

Comment: The reason you can't play the youtube video in VideoView is that it's not proper encoded, not because VideoView can't support video streaming cause it does.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code to play the youtube video in the videoview.

Comment: You issue is not that the video is on youtube. Videos on youtube are played like any other videos stored on any other server. There are a lot of questions on SO that show how to play a video in VideoView. Otherwise post your code with VideoView, that's not working.

Comment: Here is the code for videoview to play YouTube video          VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvtCk1wZ7LM&feature=player_detailpage");
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();       Let me know how can I change my code.

Comment: Code is ok. I already told you there is a problem with the video encoding. Android VideoView plays only the proper encoded videos.

Comment: So, tell me how to implement that. I have  posted  the  code.

Comment: You have to convert your video to a format accepted by Android. Try using HandBrake to encode it. Please also see : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use my little [HTML5WebView](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/), I think it should be able to play back YouTube video if turn on hardwareAccelerated in you manifest file.